# PubSub fails publication after converting to console app

Tags: sockets, tcp, connection, timeout, subscription

I am new to Pub/Sub and haven't done TCP in a decade... Please help! I have a windows forms Pub Sub application that works perfectly. After extensive testing, I converted the "Pub" app to a console app (It will eventually be a service app)... The problem is _proxy.Publish(alertData, topicName1); inside the "SendEvent()" method fails due to a timeout.

Exception stated below:

The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9529953'.

(One point of note, the entire application runs for less than 59 seconds before reaching the "Publish" command)

I've compared the WinApp and Console App side by side and don't see the problem... I've searched google and SO for over 6 hours and tried everything I can think of. Please help!!! Please point out if I'm doing something not very smart such as missed some minor, (or major) dumb, detail!!! Thank you

The effective code is below:

```
class Program
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PublisherClass pb = new PublisherClass();
        pb.PublisherClassStart();
    }
}

public class PublisherClass
{
    public List<String> ListOfTopics = new List<String>();
    public List<String> ButtonCreatedList = new List<String>();
    public List<RData> DataList = new List<RData>();
    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread listenThread;

    IPublishing _proxy;
    private System.Timers.Timer tmrEvent;

    /* static */
    TcpClient QFeedClientChannel = null;

    //call the entitiesmodel customer list and create all topics from the.... here...
    public void PublisherClassStart()
    {

        CreateProxy();
        _eventCounter = 0;

        QueueViaTCPListener();
        CreateTopics();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Send Data to Server");
        while (true)
        {
            var Val = Console.ReadLine();
            object sender = null;
            EventArgs e = null;
            SendEvent(sender, e);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(10000); // wait for connections and topics to stabilize and then start firing the timer.
        tmrEvent = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
        tmrEvent.Elapsed += SendEvent;
        tmrEvent.Start();

    }

    static public void CreateTopics()
    {
```

...
        }

```
    private void CreateProxy()
    {
        string endpointAddressInString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndpointAddress"];
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(endpointAddressInString);
        NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        _proxy = ChannelFactory<IPublishing>.CreateChannel(netTcpBinding, endpointAddress);
    }

    void SendEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            lock (ListOfTopics)
            {
                lock(DataList)
                {
                    foreach (...)
                    {
                      ...
                            alertData = PrepareEvent(topicName1, topicData);
                            _proxy.Publish(alertData, topicName1);
                            _eventCounter += 1;
                            //txtEventCount.Text = _eventCounter.ToString();

                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex )
        {
            int i = 0;
        }
        //tmrEvent.Start();            
    }
```

Comment: FYI: The failing line of code is near the very bottom... and the integer in the exception is just debug code to put a break point on...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: The problem was in the NetTCPBinding SecurityMode. During Code Review the security was changed in the publisher, then an unrelated emergency occurred that took several days to resolve, and the server NetTCPBinding hadn;t been changed to match. Watch your security settings!

NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

and you shouldn't use "none" either! Default is transport mode...